# "Ladies tracks" and "hallmark" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, indefinite-article

> When Fabolous and Jadakiss connected for their 2017 collaborative project, Friday on Elm Street, the lyrical tandem shook up the city of New York with their visceral raps. Despite being a punchy lyricist, Fab's penchant for **ladies tracks** continues to be hallmark of his. On Friday (July 13), Fab recruited Ty Dolla $ign once again for his latest earworm, "Ooh Yea." ([source](https://www.billboard.com/articles/columns/hip-hop/8465353/fabolous-ooh-yea-ty-dolla-sign))

What does "ladies tracks" refer to in this sentence? I thought it possibly means "records made by female musicians", but there seems to be no females mentioned in this article. Knowing not much about music, I can't figure out if "ladies tracks" is a thing or if I read the sentence totally wrong.

Also, since "hallmark" is a count noun, shouldn't there be an indefinite article before it? Shouldn't that part of the sentence read: "...continues to be **a** hallmark of his."?

Comment: "Ladies tracks" here means "records made for ladies", that is, songs that women/girls love to hear.

Comment: Compare **crooner** from yesteryear. You're right about ***a** hallmark of his*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo "crooner from yesteryear"? Are you referring to an ELL post? I searched for "crooner" and the only post I could find is an answer by you from 2015.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=crooner+meaning&oq=crooner+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57.4778j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I happen to know that word. I am just not sure I get your point about "crooner from yesteryear".

Comment: I can't read your cited text in context, but note that it's so badly written it's probably not worth spending time on anything you don't understand immediately.

Comment: "from yesteryear" means "from a bygone era" or similar.

Comment: I was shocked to find the link you cited was accurate. I apologise for my assumption from what you posted, that you'd misquoted something…

the real problem here is that the original text was at best semi-literate…

that being the case, what rules could ever apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I read "ladies tracks" as a misspelling of "ladies' tracks", and while you could interpret it as tracks written by women, I think it would be more commonly used to mean tracks written for women. Compare "ladies' shoes".

Second, you are correct about "a hallmark". As @FumbleFingers says, this passage has grammatical errors, so while it is an excellent exercise to test your ability to parse colloquial English through errors, it is not an example to use as a pattern for writing or speaking it correctly.